# browser menu selection using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Can anyone help me in this scenario.

Before I start with Automation testing after I open a browser instance I need to select a value in the menu . How to do it in selenium.

My exact requirement 
steps

1)Open Safari browser

2)Click on Develop in the menu bar and then select  User Agent -> Safari iOS 4.3.3 iphone

3) start with normal test execution.

Let me know the possible solution for same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. But if you need to test website under iOS Safari, there is an implementation in WebDriver - http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/IPhoneDriver